# Python twisted issue

Tags: python, logic, twisted

I am having an issue getting my twisted script to run its throwing a syntax error on line 13

```
   File "sponzyTwisted.py", line 13
   else:
   ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the code as I am using it:

```
class printStuffs(object):
    count = 0
    def count(self):
            count += 1
            print "the counter is at" + count

class controlListener(object):
      count = 0
      def count(selt):
      if self.counter == 0:
          print "Killing Process"
          reactor.stop()
      else:
          print self.counter, '...'
          self.counter -= 1
          reactor.callLater(1, self.count)

from twisted.internet import reactor

print "Printing random stuff"
reactor.callWhenRunning(printStuffs().count)

print "Intializing kill listner"
reactor.callWhenRunning(controlListner().count)
```

I literally cut and pasted this code from here:
 http://krondo.com/our-eye-beams-begin-to-twist/

So I dont think the error is due to indenting. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your actual indentation, then your indentation is off.

Your statements aren't within the scope of the function.

Comment: You got it, I had to have checked them 5 times but I did it again and it worked?

Comment: Glad it's working now. You should probably rename some of your variables though and in `def count(selt)` I think you meant `def count(self)`

Comment: yeah I noticed that just now with another error oh well thats coding